# postgres in docker container role "postgres" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, docker

1. Create a postgres docker container with below command: `docker run -v /home/ec2-user/Vteck-postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data -d -e POSTGRES_USER=odoo POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo -e POSTGRES_DB=postgres --name vteck-db postgres`
2. access Docker container:
   `docker exec -it vteck-db bash`
3. Connect with the client: `root@f1ba565db798:/# psql -U postgres psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL: role "postgres" does not exist`

but if I create Docker container with
`docker run --rm -d -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root --name postgres postgres`,
I can successfully connect with `psql - U postgres`.

Any problem with my first step's command?

Answer (score 13):

From [postgres readme on Docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres):

> ##### `POSTGRES_USER`
>
> This optional environment variable is used in conjunction with `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` to set a user and its password. This variable will create the specified user with superuser power and a database with the same name. If it is not specified, then the default user of `postgres` will be used.

In other words if you put something into the `POSTGRES_USER` environment variable, the startup script will honor that and create that user instead of the default one (`postgres`, that is).

Also, this and other `POSTGRES_*` variables are only used during the initial startup, when the database directory is empty. So if you restart the container with some other value, it won't make any difference (you'll see in logs something about "database seems ok, skipping initialization") unless you manually deleted the database.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, this helped me understand the issue, thank you, now I'm looking for the command to login to PostgreSQL with odoo, I want to connect to the DB to build a REST API

Comment: @NimrSawafta try this `docker exec -e PGPASSWORD=odoo -it POSTGRES_CONTAINER_NAME psql -U odoo `

Answer (score 1):

In your yml file, make a POSTGRES_DB that is NOT 'postgres'

```
<snip>
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: heavymetaldifficultmoeilijk
      POSTGRES_DB: foodb
<snip>
```

Connect to your container from the host:

```
# docker exec -it myproject_pg_container_name /bin/bash
```

Then, from the container:

```
root@d14c082e80c8:/# psql -U postgres
```

Michael